# Does Firefox have an equivalent to chrome://inspect?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome-devtools, inspect, node-inspector

In Chrome you can go to `chrome://inspect` to go to the debug page. Does Firefox have anything like this?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Seems similar with `about:debugging` page in Firefox.

Comment: ...But it doesn't support Node debugging due to differences in engine architectures between Mozilla's SpiderMonkey and Google's V8 used by Chrome and Node.